# C# array out of bounds exception error

Tags: c#, arrays, exception

I was looking at the code golf section and came across a very interesting coding challenge. I decided to look through the post and noticed there was an example done in C#. 
To see how it worked, I copied the code and put it into my VS to run and debug it, however, there is an issue when I run it.
(Reason I wanted to do this is because I plan on creating my own version of it with different code after I understand what the original programmer envisioned).

I get an array out of bounds exception and I have no idea why, would someone explain why the error is there and steps to correct it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace SourceCodeTranslationChallenge
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dx = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dx.Add("using", "usura");
            dx.Add("System", "Ratio");
            dx.Add("Collections", "Comprensio");
            dx.Add("Text", "Scriptum");
            dx.Add("txt", "scrptm");
            dx.Add("output", "scribo");
            dx.Add("namespace", "nomenspatium");
            dx.Add("class", "classis");
            dx.Add("Program", "Libellus");
            dx.Add("static", "immotus");
            dx.Add("void", "inane");
            dx.Add("Main", "Paelagus");
            dx.Add("string", "chorda");
            dx.Add("args", "argumenta");
            dx.Add("Dictionary", "Lexicon");
            dx.Add("new", "novus");
            dx.Add("Add", "Adaugeo");
            dx.Add("IO", "LecticoScribo");
            dx.Add("abstract", "abstracto");
            dx.Add("break", "confractus");
            dx.Add("Math", "Mathematica");
            dx.Add("File", "Ordo");
            dx.Add("file", "ordo");
            dx.Add("foreach", "prosingulus");
            dx.Add("Read", "Lectico");
            dx.Add("Write", "Scribo");
            dx.Add("All", "Omnes");
            dx.Add("translation", "interpretatio");
            dx.Add("bool", "verumfalsus");
            dx.Add("true", "verum");
            dx.Add("false", "falsus");
            dx.Add("0", "nil");
            dx.Add("||", "aut");
            dx.Add("&&", "et");
            dx.Add("Key", "Clavis");
            dx.Add("Value", "Pretium");
            dx.Add("Replace", "Restituo");
            dx.Add("Generic", "Ordinarius");
            dx.Add("ToLatin", "AdLatinam");
            string file = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);
            foreach (var translation in dx )
            {
                file = file.Replace(translation.Key, translation.Value);
            }
            File.WriteAllText("output.txt", file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what line is it throwing the error can you tell us if you used the debugger to step through the code..

Comment: what are your command line arguments? `string file = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);` is looking for a path to a txt file.

Comment: command line arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're debugging this in VS, set a breakpoint on "string file = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);" and you'll probably see that args has no length or is null.

If this is so, then in the project settings => debug section, there is a command line arguments box that you can set a valid file path in (For example, C:\YourFile.txt).

Once you do this, try debugging it again and args[0] should have a value in it.

Answer (score 4):

Do you simply run this program by running the executable? If so, you are doing it wrong. The program requires the file to be sent in the argument string. So, to test it, just "Open With" the input file using this program.